# Wordpress Archive URL rewriting

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have custom wordpress post types with custom Taxonomies.

On the archive page I am trying to query 2 custom custom taxonomies.

```
Archive template is "archive-job_listing.php"
```

Wordpress URL is :

```
example.com/?job_listing_region=pune&job_listing_category=wordpress
```

WP rewrite code:

```
function ao_add_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule( 'pune/wordpress', '?job_listing_region=pune&job_listing_category=wordpress', 'top');
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}


add_action( 'init', 'ao_add_rewrite_rule');
```

The URL should come as

```
example.com/pune/wordpress
```

When I add above code nothing happens. I flushed the URL's (permalinks)

PS: I have written regex to make all the query strings as URL's working. But that was not working. So I wanted to get this simple one working.

Comment: Just a note on your `flush_rewrite_rules()` -- you don't want to run that every time, just once i.e. plugin deactivation or activation. It's an expensive operation, so Wordpress caches the rewrite rules.  Clicking Save Changes in Permalinks does the same thing.

More info in [offical docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/).

Answer (score 0):

> Don't forget to click Save Changes in Permalinks Settings.

Try following:

```
function ao_add_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?job_listing_region=$matches[1]&job_listing_category=$matches[2]', 'top');
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}


add_action( 'init', 'ao_add_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: This is working not working. If i remove index.php it working for wp admin and its breaking. Just a remainder I am using archieve and template is archive-job_listing.php as mentioned in my question.

Comment: did you save `job_listing_region` and `job_listing_category` into query variables

Comment: Yes I am using query strings. I tried this but its woking and its showing 404 for innermost page, the when some one clicks on any post on this page its showing 404(/wordpress/pune/job-name-1), so this rule is effecting that page. Any idea of where i am going wrong?